# How to "short circuit"/conditionally add run union clause in a mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I am selecting some rows from different tables
The logic is like this:
I want to return in total only 10 results, I try first table_a and if I cannot fetch 10 rows from table_a I fill the remaining rows from the results fetched from table_b

Pseudo-query

```
   select value from table_a limit 10
   union # ONLY IF COULD NOT FETCH 10 values from table_a
   (select value from table_b limit 10)
   limit 10
```

Is something like this possible in mysql and if yes how ?

Some simple test cases

**test case 1:** that if I can fetch 10 rows form table_a don't want to execute the union as I have enough results.

**test case 2:** I got 4 values(rows) from table_a then union executes and I get N more rows from table_b, in total should never get more than 10 rows (limit 10)

**test case 3:**
0 items in table_a, the query will only return up to at most 10 items from table_b

PS:
I am aware and know how to solve this via the programming language.

In that case would be as easy as:

```
$queryA = 'select value from table_a limit 10';
$results = $sql->execute($queryA);
if (count($results) < 10) {
  $queryB = sprint('select value from table_b limit %d', 10 - count($results));
  $resultsB = $sql->execute($queryB);
  $results = $results + $resultsB;
}
```

I wonder if can be done in a more elegant minimal way directly from mysql

Comment: If you don't want to run the second query unless the first returns fewer than 10 rows, then do it in code as you show.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dummy column to count the rows from table_a and then can use a sub-query to have your desired result -

```
SELECT value
  FROM (SELECT 1 as src, value
          FROM table_a
         UNION
        SELECT 2 as src, value
          FROM table_b
        ORDER BY src
        LIMIT 10
       ) x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that will not "short circuit" or stop the select 2... the part after union from being executed

Comment: Even if that step executed, You will only get the 10 records from table_a only. If it does not have 10 records, Then only it will include records from table_b.

Comment: I know and understand that but will still execute the query and wait until those 10 rows are calculated and fetched. I am curious to know if there is a way to not execute the second query if have already 10 rows from first query therefore not wait X ms/s for the second query

Comment: Since I am using LIMIT 10. So it will never executes 2nd query if you get 10 rows from table_a only.